# IHostBUilder enforce previous actions

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my program.cs for my .net core WebApplication, I have two lines of code that needs. The ordering matters. AddResolver must be done and completed before UseApm.

Webapplication program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddResolver();
builder.Host.UseApm();
```

This works perfectly. But unfortuantely when I try this in a  IHostBuilder, I'm unable to get the resolver to resolve before UseApm.

HostBuilder program.cs

```
var host =  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(ctx =>
                    {
                        ctx.AddResolver(); 
                    })
                .UseApm()
```

I'm wondering is there a way I can enforce AddResolver in HostBuilder. Maybe if there was a way to access IConfigurationBuilder and it's not an action. The right question to ask might be how do I access IConfigurationBuilder through IHostBuilder without it wrapped in an action.

Comment: What is `Addresolver` and `UseApm`? Can you please provide a [mre]?